# Trying to import data from a csv file into mysql database using phpadmin

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to move my project over to another web hosting service.  I was able to export and import all the databases ok, with the corresponding tables.

I'm trying to move the data over now by exporting it to a csv file and then mnporting it.
I keep getting a error that says
"Invalid field count in CSV input on line 1."
This does not make sense to me.  The table has 16 rows, I loaded it into a excel database and the csv file has 16 rows.

I am going from
php admin version 3.5.8 to version 2.8.0.1

Comment: Export the data as an SQL script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Invalid field count in CSV input on line *` tells that there is a mismatch between number of columns in the table and number of values in CSV which we try import. The two must be equal and it doesn't bother about the number of rows anyway. Here is an example

[image: test table]

this is a sample table which contains 8 columns. and take a look at my csv which i tried to import.
[image]

in Line 1 I tried to insert insufficient values, which will trigger the `Invalid field count` error. **So inspect your CSV file that it has enough count of insert values.**

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use mysqldump?

```
commandline_of_your_choice#> mysqldump -uusername -p -hlocalhost DB_Name --single-transaction | mysql -uusername -p -hremotehost DB_Name
```

and that's it